# FB.login popup window goes right side when browser maximized

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, fb.ui

When I call fb.login it opens the popup window at right side of the screen (not the center). 
It is happening when i tried it in maximized browser of IE and FF but when tried in Chrome it goes to center. Also for IE and FF if the browser is not maximized, it is also goes center.

How can i set its position to go always center?